# Create Snapshot for Databases with Multiple Data Files in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create database snapshot for databases which have primary data file (.mdf) and secondary data files (.ndf files) too.
Throws exception Missing the file databaseName_EX when I create it.
The database file includes databaseName_EX.ndf and databaseName.mdf

```
CREATE DATABASE databaseName_report_snap ON
(Name ='databaseNameJ',
FileName='E:\SqlData\databaseName_report.snp')
AS SNAPSHOT OF databaseName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE databaseName_report_snap ON
(Name ='databaseName',
FileName='E:\SqlData\databaseName_report.snp'),
(Name ='databaseName_EX',
FileName='E:\SqlData\databaseName_report_ext.snp')
AS SNAPSHOT OF databaseName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote following SP for taking snapshot of database with multiple files. It may help somebody stumble upon this question.

```
/*************************************************************************
DATE          VERSION             NAME                    REFERENCE
2018-03-08    Utility             Utsav Verma             Admin Task

▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ஜ۩۞۩ஜ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
This SP will create snapshot of given DB on given path.
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ஜ۩۞۩ஜ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬

Parameters:
@DBName                   : name of the database to be retsored
@FileGroupDestinationPath : location where snapshot database files will be placed

EXAMPLE CALL

EXEC dbo.USP_CreateSnapshotOfDB 
  @DBName='DBNAME',  
  @FileGroupDestinationPath ='C:\Work\Tmp\';
GO
**************************************************************************/
USE master
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USP_CreateSnapshotOfDB(
  @DBName nvarchar(256),
  @FileGroupDestinationPath nvarchar(512))
AS
begin  
  DECLARE 
    @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @SSDBName sysname;
  
  SELECT @SSDBName=name FROM sys.databases WHERE source_database_id=(SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE name=@DBName);
  SELECT @SQL='DROP DATABASE '+ @SSDBName;
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DBObjects' , 'U') IS NOT NULL
   drop TABLE ##DBObjects

  SELECT TOP(0) DB= CONVERT(sysname,''), *
  INTO ##DBObjects
  FROM sys.database_files

  EXEC sp_Msforeachdb 'use [?];INSERT INTO ##DBObjects select ''[?]'', * from sys.database_files ';

  SELECT @SQL='';
  SELECT @SQL='ALTER DATABASE '+@DBName+' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; ';
  SELECT @SQL+='CREATE DATABASE '+@DBName+'_SnapShot ON ';
  SELECT @SQL+='(NAME='+NAME+',filename='''+@FileGroupDestinationPath+'\'+NAME+'''),'
  FROM ##DBObjects 
  WHERE db='['+@DBName+']' AND type_desc<>'LOG';
  SELECT @SQL=substring(@SQL,1,len(@SQL)-1);

  SELECT @SQL+= ' AS SNAPSHOT OF '+@DBName +'; ';
  SELECT @SQL+='ALTER DATABASE '+@DBName+' SET MULTI_USER;';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

END
GO
```

Comment: What does the first table drop do ?